# Fastest way to find and replace inside a large amount of files

Tags: c#, optimization, unity3d

Currently I am looping through dependencies of objects, and I am trying to replace GUID (unity object ID's) inside the files. 
Right now I am using the following code, any suggestions for improvement ?

```
public class SendToThread
{
    public int localID = 0;
    public string oldID;
    public string newID;
    public List<string> dependencyAssetPath = new List<string>();
    public string applicationPath;
}

public void Charlie()
{
    //toUseData is a List<SendToThread>
    for (int i = 0 ; i < toUseData.Count; i++)
    {
        while (toUseData[i].dependencyAssetPath.Count >= 1)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(toUseData[i].applicationPath + toUseData[i].dependencyAssetPath[0]);

            for (int e = 0; e < lines.Length; e++)
            {
                DebugVoid(lines.Length.ToString());
                lines[e].Replace(toUseData[i].oldID.ToString(), toUseData[i].newID.ToString());

                if (e == lines.Length - 1)
                {
                    DebugVoid(toUseData[i].oldID.ToString() + "  " + toUseData[i].newID.ToString());
                    File.WriteAllLines(toUseData[i].applicationPath + toUseData[i].dependencyAssetPath[i], lines);
                }
            }
            toUseData[i].dependencyAssetPath.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Charlie` may just be the worst method name I've ever seen. Normally, methods are verbs. They aren't really ever people.

Comment: @Magus Its the naming sense for threads we use here. Thread 1) alpha 2)beta 3) charlie. Charlie is a thread running independently from the unity engine, this to prevent unity engine freezes. So Its not a name, its phonetic alphabet ;)

Comment: Time to go `Charlie` up some `GameObject`. Sorry, but even if you mean that it should do something with the third thread, it's a horrible name, because it doesn't convey that. Even if you understand that it's the name of the third thread, then what? What is happening to it? I think I'll just go and `Rhode Island`.

Comment: Have you considered `Parallel.For`? You might give it a shot and see if there's any discernible performance increase.

Comment: Alpha, Beta, Charlie? What? Shouldn't it be Alpha, Beta, Gamma or Alpha, Bravo, Charlie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- don't call `ToString ()` on Strings
- the `e == lines.Length - 1` should be outside of the loop
- extract the processing of the  `toUseData` to a separare   method
- I would avoid public fields. Use properties instead

To expand [Nick Udell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/41237/nick-udell)'s [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64555/29371) which has been a good start

> ```
> public void ReadAssets()
> {
>     //toUseData is a List<SendToThread>
>     foreach (var toUse in toUseData)
>     {
>         foreach (var assetPath in toUse.DependencyAssetPath)
>         {
>             string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(toUse.ApplicationPath + assetPath);
>
>             for (int e = 0; e < lines.Length - 1; e++)
>             {
>                 DebugVoid(lines.Length.ToString());
>                 lines[e].Replace(toUse.OldID, toUse.NewID);
>             }
>
>             DebugVoid(toUse.OldID + "  " + toUse.NewID);
>             File.WriteAllLines(toUse.ApplicationPath + assetPath, lines);
>         }
>         toUse.dependencyAssetPath.Clear();
>     }
> }
> ```

We should also integrate the points already said. So let us break it into smaller methods.
To process each `SendToThread` of the list we introduce a new method `ProcessSingleItem()`.

```
private void ProcessSingleItem(SendToThread item)
{
    foreach (String assetPath in item.DependencyAssetPath)
    {
        ProcessSingleItem(item.ApplicationPath + assetPath, item.OldID, item.NewID);
    }
    item.DependencyAssetPath.Clear();
}
```

to process each item of the `item.DependencyAssetPath` property we introduce an overloaded `ProcessSingleItem()`.

```
private void ProcessSingleItem(String fileName, String oldId, String newId)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

    File.WriteAllText(fileName, ProcessLines(lines, oldId, newId));
}
```

To process the lines of the file we introduce a new method `ProcessLines()`

```
private String ProcessLines(IEnumerable<String> lines, String oldId, String newId)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2048);
    foreach (String line in lines)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(line.Replace(oldId, newId));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

and reduce the former method `Charlie`, after we rename it to `ProcessAssests`, which may not the best name but better than `Charlie`, to

```
public void ProcessAssests()
{
    //toUseData is a List<SendToThread>
    foreach (SendToThread item in toUseData)
    {
        ProcessSingleItem(item);
    }
}
```

In this way our code is better to read and to maintain.

Answer (score 4):

Building on what Heslacher and Magus have said:

[You should not make publically accessible non-readonly collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327.aspx). So I've converted those to readonly collections. It didn't appear to change how you were accessing them anyway.

I've also swapped your outermost for loop for a foreach, which makes the code slightly cleaner and I've swapped your while loop for a foreach, because it appears to just be iterating over the collection. However this assumes that

```
File.WriteAllLines(toUseData[i].applicationPath + toUseData[i].dependencyAssetPath[i], lines);
```

is a bug and should instead be

```
File.WriteAllLines(toUseData[i].applicationPath + toUseData[i].dependencyAssetPath[0], lines);
```

If not, then the while loop should be used.

Resulting version:

```
public class SendToThread
{
    private int localId = 0;
    public int LocalID
    {
        get{ return localId;}
        set{ localId = value;}
    }
    public string OldID {get; set;}
    public string NewID {get; set;}
    private readonly List<string> dependencyAssetPath = new List<string>();
    public List<string> DependencyAssetPath
    {
        get{ return dependencyAssetPath;}
    }
    public string ApplicationPath {get; set;}
}

public void ReadAssets()
{
    //toUseData is a List<SendToThread>
    foreach(var toUse in toUseData)
    {
        foreach(var assetPath in toUse.DependencyAssetPath)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(toUse.ApplicationPath + assetPath);

            for (int e = 0; e < lines.Length-1; e++)
            {
                DebugVoid(lines.Length.ToString());
                lines[e].Replace(toUse.OldID, toUse.NewID);
            }

            DebugVoid(toUse.OldID + "  " + toUse.NewID);
            File.WriteAllLines(toUse.ApplicationPath + assetPath, lines);
        }
        toUse.dependencyAssetPath.Clear();
    }
}
```